# redirect 301 with query string doesn't seem to work

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I need to redirect some URL with query string to a different URL

like

```
 redirect 301 /web/works/?id=1  https://www.example.com/it/my_work_new_page/
```

.htaccess seem to ignore this

but if i add

```
redirect 301 /it/fake/  http://www.test.it
```

it works

I already have a file with about 100 of this redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot match query string using `Redirect` directive. Use `mod_rewrite` with a `RewriteCond` directive like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /web/works/\?id=1\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com/it/my_work_new_page/? [L,#=301]
```

`?` in the target will strip previously existing query string.

#### References:

- [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)
- [Apache mod_rewrite Technical Details](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html)

Comment: I guess it will be faster in PHP. Thanks!

Comment: Actually doing it in `mod_rewrite` will always be faster than doing it in PHP.

Comment: I mean I can find a faster way to write it down :-)